# React exporting withRouter and withStyles error

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I am using react along with redux and material-ui to make a component.  I am attempting to write an export statement `export default connect()(withRouter(FirstPage))(withStyles(styles)(FirstPage))`

However, this doesn't seem to work I get an error that says

`TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined`

`this.props = props;`

This error is referencing one of my node_modules.

Here is my full code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const styles = theme =>({
    root: {
        maxWidth: 345,
    },

})
class FirstPage extends Component {
    state = {
        feeling: ''
    }

    //This function will dispatch the users response to index.js
    //The dispatch type here is 'SET_FEELING'
    submitData=(event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.dispatch({type: 'SET_FEELING', payload: this.state})
        this.changeLocation();
    }

    //This function will update the local state with the users response
    handleChange= (event) => {
        this.setState({
            feeling: event.target.value
        })
    }

    //This function will change the current url when a button is clicked
    changeLocation= ()=> {
        this.props.history.push('/secondPage')
    }

    render(){
        const { classes } = this.props;

        return(
            <div>
                <Card >
                    <CardContent className={classes.root}>

                        <form>
                        <input onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder='How are you feeling' value={this.state.feeling} />
                        </form>
                    </CardContent>
                    <CardActions>
                        <Button onClick={this.submitData}>Submit</Button>
                    </CardActions>
                </Card>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

//this export connects the component to the reduxStore as well as allowing us to use the history props
export default connect()(withRouter(FirstPage))(withStyles(styles)(FirstPage))
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I believe the following code should work:

```
export default withRouter(connect()(withStyles(styles)(FirstPage)))
```

Instead of

```
export default connect()(withRouter(FirstPage))(withStyles(styles)(FirstPage))
```

First of all, `connect()` returns a function that only accepts an argument. Second, `connect()` should be wrapped inside `withRouter()`. This problem is stated in the github docs of [React Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md).

Comment: No problem. Glad to help

Comment: can we achieve this without react-redux? By using only react-router-dom?

Comment: @AS490 yes, you should be able to do `export default withRouter(withStyles(styles)(FirstPage))`

Comment: Hi @BrianLe: working fine i have tried like this way `export default withRouter((withStyles(useStyles)(Navbar)));`

Comment: I know this is 8 months old but thanks.  I get confused with these wraps on my components no matter how many times I do them it seems.  This worked great for me.  I auth route was not forwarding props and hence directing react router to render the new authenticated route.  This wrapping fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

without using `react-redux` :

```
export default (withStyles(styles), withRouter)(FirstPage);
```